# Black and Scholes Model

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

Can someone please explain, where the term $S^2$ (while applying Ito's Lemma in the solution of a PDE of a Geometric Brownian Motion) comes from? 
$$
\frac{\sigma^2 \color{red}S^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial S^2} 
$$

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

$S_t=\mu S_t\,dt+\sigma S_t\,dW_t$

Ito's Lemma yields
$$
dV(S_t)=V'(S_t)\,dS_t+\frac12V''(S_t)\,d\langle S\rangle_t
$$

If $dX_t=K_t\,dt+H_t\,dW_t$ then by definition $d\langle X\rangle_t=H_t^2\,dt$. So here we have $d\langle S\rangle_t=\sigma^2S_t^2\,dt$.